# Emacs in Gentoo Prefix not receiving input

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-mountain-lion, gentoo

I have Emacs installed in a Gentoo Prefix installation on OS-X (10.8.2).  Emacs works when started in a terminal (-nw).  However, when started without options, although it creates a window, it does not receive input from the keyboard - input goes to the shell that started emacs. Mouse input seems ok, but the application menu that runs along the top of the screen (separate from the emacs window) still says "Terminal".

Here is the list of options used (I didn't touch USE flags so this is the default).  I notice that 'aqua' is ON and 'X' is OFF, which seems right (the X server is not installed).

```
~/Gentoo $ emerge -pv emacs

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] app-editors/emacs-24.2:24::gentoo [24.2:24::gentoo_prefix] USE="aqua xpm 
    -X -Xaw3d (-alsa) -athena -dbus -games -gconf -gif -gnutls (-gpm) -gsettings -gtk -gtk3 
    -gzip-el (-hesiod) -imagemagick -jpeg -kerberos -libxml2 -livecd (-m17n-lib) -motif 
    -pax_kernel -png (-selinux) -sound -source -svg -tiff -toolkit-scroll-bars -wide-int 
    -xft" 0 kB

Total: 1 package (1 reinstall), Size of downloads: 0 kB
~/Gentoo $
```

I could rebuild with 'X' turned on, but it would be nice to keep the native build. 
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered the problem of a gui app (SAGA GIS on OS X Snow Leopard) started from the terminal creating a window but not generating the SAGA application menu.  The solution is to wrap the program in an "app bundle", see:

[Compiling SAGA on Mac OS X](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20SAGA%20on%20Mac%20OS%20X)

Even with this, SAGA is not fully usable.  As for emacs, I have have emacs-app 24.3.1 installed via macports (supports both native and X modes), but find that it sometimes ignores keyboard input when asking for a "yes or no" answer -- the only way I have found to recover is to kill the emacs process.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I don't think I resolved the problem within Prefix, but I found that Emacs builds easily natively on Emacs (using Aqua, not X) and runs pretty well.  It hangs very occasionally but not often enough to be a bother.